# Show that $x$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/x^3+y^3-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have no idea about it. Others said that every coset has a unique representative of the form $f(X)+g(x)Y+h(X)Y^2$, and then it is easy to see that $x \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]/x^3+y^3-1$ is irreducible. But I still don't understand it.

I hope you can give some suggestions to help me understand it or show other ways to prove it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question seems sort of related to the one from yesterday [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3731142/is-mathbbcx-y-x3y3%E2%88%921-is-a-ufd-or-not)?

Comment: Yes. But i still have trouble at this point